# $(a^{-1})^{-1} = a$ in a groupoid: proof review

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, groupoids

[Exercise on groupoids article](https://www.matem.unam.mx/%7Eomar/groupoids/day1.html): Show that in a groupoid, $$
  (a^{-1})^{-1} = a \,.
$$

Proof: Every element must have an inverse, and likewise each element’s inverse must itself have an inverse (e.g., $a^{-1}$ must have an inverse $(a^{-1})^{-1})$, so $((a^{-1})^{-1} a^{-1}) a = a$, hence $(a^{-1})^{-1} ((a^{-1}) a) = a$ and thus $(a^{-1})^{-1} = a$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Yes, it is the same proof as in a group.

Comment: In the title you ask whether inverses of groupoids are unique. This is different from the proof of $(a^{-1})^{-1}=a$

Comment: @Peter I changed the title. Thanks for catching that - that's precisely why I would post such a simple question: to see what I might have missed!

Comment: yes, this proof is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blog post in question defines things in the following way:

> A groupoid is a set with a partially defined multiplication such that
>
> 1. $a(bc) = (ab)c$, that is, whenever one side is defined so if the other and they are equal; additionally, when both $ab$ and $bc$ and are defined, so is $a(bc)$.
> 2. every element $a$ has an inverse $a^{-1}$ such that both $a a^{-1}$ and $a^{-1} a$ are defined, [and] these products behave as identities “as much as possible”, namely, whenever $ab$ is defined, $a^{-1} a b = b$ and $a b b^{-1} = a$.

You start by (correctly) observing that $(a^{-1})^{-1} a^{-1} a = a$.
But I don’t see how to conclude from this single equation that $(a^{-1})^{-1} = a$.

I was originally not sure if the statement was even true, so I checked it in (too) much detail below.
However, we can also give a short argument:
abbreviating $a^{-1}$ and $(a^{-1})^{-1}$ as $a'$ and $a''$ respectively, we have
$$
  a
  = a'' a' a
  = a'' a' (a a' a'')
  = a'' (a' a a') a''
  = a'' a' a''
  = a'' \,.
$$

---

The long and tedious argumentation goes as follows:

The element $(a^{-1})^{-1}$ is defined via certain conditions.
We show that $(a^{-1})^{-1} = a$ by showing that the element $a$ satisfies these conditions.

More precisely, the element $(a^{-1})^{-1}$ is uniquely determined by the following four conditions:

- $a^{-1} (a^{-1})^{-1}$ is defined.
- $(a^{-1})^{-1} a^{-1}$ is defined.
- whenever $a^{-1} b$ is defined, $(a^{-1})^{-1} a^{-1} b = b$.
- whenever $b a^{-1}$ is defined, $b a^{-1} (a^{-1})^{-1} = b$.

We hence need to check that the element $a$ satisfies all of these conditions, when $(a^{-1})^{-1}$ is replaced by $a$.
More explicitly, we need to check the following four conditions:

1. $a^{-1} a$ is defined.
2. $a a^{-1}$ is defined.
3. whenever $a^{-1} b$ is defined, $aa^{-1} b = b$,
4. whenever $b a^{-1}$ is defined, $b a^{-1} a = b$.

To show these four conditions we are allowed to use all of the following:

- A. $x(yz)$ is defined if and only if $(xy)z$ is defined, and then both sides are equal (for arbitrary $x, y, z$).

Instead of $x(yz)$ or $(xy)z$, we then use the simplified notation $xyz$.
We will also use larger versions of associativity without further proof.

- B. If $xy$ and $yz$ are defined, then $xyz$ is defined (for arbitrary $x, y, z$).
- C. $x x^{-1}$ is defined (for arbitrary $x$).
- D. $x^{-1} x$ is defined (for arbitrary $x$).
- E. Whenever $xy$ is defined, $x^{-1} x y = y$ (for arbitrary $x, y$).
- F. Whenever $yx$ is defined, $y x x^{-1} = y$ (for arbitrary $x, y$).

This is enough to show 1, 2, 3 and 4.

1. The first condition follows from D with $x = a$.
2. The second condition follows from C with $x = a$.
3. Suppose that $a^{-1} b$ is defined.
   Since $a a^{-1}$ is defined by 2, it follows that $a a^{-1} b$ is defined.
   We need to show that this element equals $b$.
   We know that $a^{-1} a$ is defined by 1, it follows that $a^{-1} a a^{-1} b$ is defined.
   It follows from E (with $x = a$ and $y = a^{-1} b$) that $a^{-1} a a^{-1} b = a^{-1} b$.
   It follows from D that $(a^{-1})^{-1} a^{-1}$ is defined, whence we can extend the equality $a^{-1} a a^{-1} b = a^{-1} b$ to the equality
   $$
     (a^{-1})^{-1} a^{-1} a a^{-1} b = (a^{-1})^{-1} a^{-1} b \,.
   $$
   But we know from E (with $x = a^{-1}$ and $y = a a^{-1} b$) that the left-hand site of this equation equals $a a^{-1} b$, and we also know from E (with $x = a^{-1}$ and $y = b$) that the right-hand side equals $b$.
   Therefore, $a a^{-1} b = b$, as desired.
4. Suppose now that $b a^{-1}$ is defined.
   We know from 1 that $a^{-1} a$ is defined, so it follows that $b a^{-1} a$ is defined.
   We need to show that this element equals $b$.
   We know that $a a^{-1}$ is defined by 2, so it follows that $b a^{-1} a a^{-1}$ is defined.
   We know from F (with $y = b a^{-1}$ and $x = a$) that $b a^{-1} a a^{-1} = b a^{-1}$.
   We know from C that $a^{-1} (a^{-1})^{-1}$ is defined, whence we can extend the equality $b a^{-1} a a^{-1} = b a^{-1}$ to the equality
   $$
     b a^{-1} a a^{-1} (a^{-1})^{-1} = b a^{-1} (a^{-1})^{-1} \,.
   $$
   We know from F (with $y = b a^{-1} a$ and $x = a^{-1}$) that the left-hand side of this equation equals $b a^{-1} a$, and we also know from F (with $y = b$ and $x = a^{-1}$ that the right-side equals $b$.
   Therefore, $b a^{-1} a = b$, as desired.

In short form, the above two argumentations read as
$$
  a a^{-1} b
  = (a^{-1})^{-1} a^{-1} a a^{-1} b
  = (a^{-1})^{-1} a^{-1} b
  = b
$$
and
$$
  b a^{-1} a
  = b a^{-1} a a^{-1} (a^{-1})^{-1}
  = b a^{-1} (a^{-1})^{-1}
  = b \,.
$$

Comment: "You start by (correctly) observing that (a−1)−1a−1a=a. But I don’t see how to conclude from this single equation that (a−1)−1=a"... Whats wrong with what op writes?

Comment: I'll be honest, your argument seems like overkill. I don't see whats wrong with op's reasoning, so, if you see a mistake, maybe you should point out specifically what they do wrong.

Comment: @IsAdisplayName OP’s entire reasoning is $a = ((a^{-1})^{-1} a^{-1}) a = (a^{-1})^{-1} (a^{-1} a)$, with the second equality being a trivial associativity step. There is no mistake in these equations, but there is no argument for why this would prove the required equality $(a^{-1})^{-1} = a$. And I claim that this conclusion is non-obvious with the very specific non-standard definition of a groupoid that the question is built upon. If it is clear to you how $(a^{-1})^{-1} = a$ immediatelly follows from these two equations, feel free to add an explanation as a comment.

Comment: Since $a^{-1}a=1$, the desired claim follows from op's equality

Comment: @IsAdisplayName Please actually read the definition of a groupoid that OP uses (see the link in their post). There exists no $1$ in this definition.

Comment: Yeah, I did read the definitions. the "=1" could be taken as shorthand for "behaves like an identity" . Plus, there's two definitions given in the article, one of which actually has identities. And op didn't mention which definition they needed to use. I think it's fair to assume the standard definition in that case. Either way, didn't mean to say your approach is mistaken

Comment: (1) OP’s question appears directly underneath the first, non-standard definition, whereas the second definition only starts two paragraphs later. The quoted question can therefore only refer to the first definition. (2) The second definition still has no $1$’s. It’s only another (long) exercise later that these become available. (And this may even rely on $(a^{-1})^{-1} = a$.) (3) You could define “$= 1$” to mean “behaves like an identity” in such a way that $a^{-1} a = 1$ implies $b a^{-1} a = b$.  But then you need to prove that $a^{-1} a = 1$, since this isn’t covered by the definition.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your answers. I was worried that this question was so simple it might not even provoke a response. but glad to see I was proven wrong!

Comment: @JendrikStelzner fair enough. Though I had meant to use "behaves" like an identity in the way the author uses it in the definition